# jquery select after all elements with certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few divs with the same class.  The divs are generated dynamically, so I don't always know the exact number of these divs.

I want to place another div after the last div.

```
<div class="someclassname">content here</div>
<div class="someclassname">content here</div>
<div class="someclassname">content here</div>
```

When I do this:

```
$('.someclassname').after('place another div here');
```

It places it after each one.
Is there a way to select the last div with .someclassname?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's last selector like so:

```
$('.someclassname:last').after('place another div here');
```

If you want to select the last **div** with someclassname, and no other element type, then use this instead:

```
$('div.someclassname:last').after('place another div here');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.someclassname:last').after('place another div here');
```